# Resetting a synced Android Chrome profile

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android

I would like to clear whatever settings I have enabled in Android Chrome *and have the resulting clean profile synchronised*. I have synchronisation of Google Chrome enabled on Android, but there are some settings that I need to clear to factory/default settings. Obviously, if I clear *all app data and settings* using the normal Android approach, my login state be cleared as well, so the resulting *clean* profile will not be synchronised to the cloud. There seems to be a bit of a Catch-22 here ...

I basically just want to overwrite whatever data was previously pushed into the cloud with a clean Chrome factory settings profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your Chrome profile settings to defaults at `chrome://settings/reset` (site won't let me link because it doesn't begin with https://, sorry). This is the simplest version of a Chrome profile reset, but is only accessible via a desktop browser, *not directly via Chrome on Android*.

This will reset the settings related to your Chrome profile as detailed when you click the button on that page:

> This action will:
>
> • Reset some Chrome settings and Chrome shortcuts
> • Disable extensions
> • Delete cookies and other temporary site data

It's possible to clear *all* data associated with your Chrome profile from your Android device at the [Google Chrome Sync](https://chrome.google.com/sync) page. This will erase all of the following:

- Address bar
- History
- Bookmarks
- Reading list
- Open tabs
- Addresses
- Payment methods
- Passwords
- Settings
- Apps
- Extensions
- Themes

Also keep in mind:

> This will clear your Chrome and ChromeOS data that has been saved in your Google Account. This might clear some data from your devices.
> This will also remove your sync passphrase. You can create a new passphrase.

Comment: I know that Android Chrome does not have `chrome://settings`, but maybe the sub-resource with reset has been implemented. Checking!

Comment: Nope. `chrome://settings/reset` does not work on Android. You just get a `ERR_INVALID_URL` error page.

Comment: Sorry, that one is only accessible from the Chrome browser on desktop - I can add that in the answer. The second link will work from Android, and will generate a completely new/clean Chrome profile.

Comment: The Google Chrome Sync page was the most pertinent one. thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you!